# Discrepancy between my results of Great Conjunction 2020 and Wikipedia

Tags: celestial-mechanics, skyfield

Using python-skyfield to calculate the upcoming conjunction of Jupiter and Saturn. I'm off a few minutes with the times on Wikipedia.

[Wikipedia Great conjunction times (1800 to 2100)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Great_conjunction&oldid=986073756#List_of_great_conjunctions_(1800_to_2100))

**Using Right Ascension:**

- Dec 21,2020 13:22:00 UTC - Wikipedia.
- Dec 21,2020 13:34:33 UTC - My Calculation.

**Using Ecliptic Longitude:**

- Dec 21,2020 18:37:31 UTC - Wikipedia
- Dec 21,2020 18:20:40 UTC - My Calculation.

```
from skyfield.api import load, tau, pi
from skyfield.almanac import find_discrete

planets = load('de421.bsp')
sun = planets['sun']
earth = planets['earth']
jupiter = planets['jupiter barycenter']
saturn = planets['saturn barycenter']

ts = load.timescale(builtin=True)

def longitude_difference(t):
    e = earth.at(t)
    j = e.observe(jupiter).apparent()
    s = e.observe(saturn).apparent()
    _, lon1, _ = s.ecliptic_latlon()
    _, lon2, _ = j.ecliptic_latlon()
    return (lon1.degrees - lon2.degrees) > 0

def longitude_difference1(t):
    e = earth.at(t)
    j = e.observe(jupiter).apparent()
    s = e.observe(saturn).apparent()

    jRa, _, _ = j.radec()
    sRa, _, _ = s.radec()
    return (sRa._degrees - jRa._degrees) > 0


longitude_difference.rough_period = 300.0
longitude_difference1.rough_period = 300.0

print()
print("Great conjunction in ecliptic longitude:")
t, b = find_discrete(ts.utc(2020), ts.utc(2021), longitude_difference)
for ti in t:
    print(t.utc_jpl())

print()
print("Great conjunction in right ascension:")
t, b = find_discrete(ts.utc(2020), ts.utc(2021), longitude_difference1)
for ti in t:
    print(t.utc_jpl())
```

Can anyone verify the correct UTC time?  Is there a bug in my code?

Comment: The wikipedia article gives a table of numbers without any source, which is poor form for them. Your difference of ten-ish minutes makes me wonder if either calculation takes into account the observer’s latitude and longitude, or imagines an observer at Earth’s center.

Comment: @rob interesting point! Just by itself the Earth takes about 7 minutes to move its own diameter, with all three orbiting the same direction the differences could be longer.

Answer (score 1):

There are no bugs in your codes. But you can make it more accurate with the following corrections (additions):

1. Using new ephemeris series (de430 or de440) most recent one is de440.
2. Use True equinox of True epoch of the date. Adding `epoch='date'` as below:

```
.radec(epoch='date')
.ecliptic_latlon(epoch='date')
```

3. use the following codes for loading timescale instead of `ts = load.timescale(builtin=True)`.

```
url = load.build_url('finals2000A.all')
with load.open(url) as f:
    finals_data = iers.parse_x_y_dut1_from_finals_all(f)

ts = load.timescale()
iers.install_polar_motion_table(ts, finals_data)
```

These codes load the updated values of ΔT and also apply `polar motion`. Of course, because your calculations are *geocentric*, the polar motion does not affect the result.

You can reach the following result by the corrections and some extra calculations for other attributes.

JUPITER -- SATURN Conjunction 2020:

- A.D. 2020-Dec-21 18:20:37.3129 UT
- Angular Separation: +  0° 06ʹ 06.38154ʺ
- JUPITER is -  0° 06ʹ 06.98608ʺ of ('Below', 'Right') of SATURN in direction of (+  0° 00ʹ 02.56845ʺ, N)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SPICE library, de440.bsp, jup310.bsp, sat375.bsp, converged Newtonian light time correction and stellar aberration correction ("CN+S").
I see that you consider Jupiter and Saturn barycenter. I'm using the planets (not their barycenter), the difference is a few seconds.

**Smallest geocentric angular separation**: 2020-12-21 18:21:05.282 UTC, separation = 6.1'

**Using Right Ascension**: 2020-12-21 13:34:40.590 UTC

**Using Ecliptic Longitude**: 2020-12-21 18:20:45.176 UTC